# Zsh path autocompletion in dotfiles git

Tags: oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion, dotfiles

I use the following alias from [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dotfiles) to have a dotfiles git

```
alias dotfiles='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME'
```

This works, however path autocompletion doesn't work in zsh. The desired behavior is, as it is for other git repos in zsh, that `dotfiles add TAB` offers a list of changed files in the repo. However, i only see briefly three dots, and then no suggestions. Note that the completion of git commands works so `dotfiles TAB` offers add, status, etc. I use oh-my-zsh and powerlevel10k. The only other description of this exact problem I have found is [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/kcgtfx/autocompletion_of_files_with_bare_git_repo/), but it is unsolved. As the automcompletion seems to work in principle, I would guess the problem is, that the zsh autocompletion script fails somehow for the bare repo.